# 'onbeforeunload' Fires Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I want to send an ajax request when a user leaves a page or closes the window.
Here is my code inside :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendajax(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "someurl",
          data: mydata,
          async : false
        });   
    }
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onbeforeunload=function(){sendajax();};
</script>
```

When the event occurs the event fires twice.
Why does in happen?
I know I can prevent it by adding a variable `var ajaxSent=true;` but may be there is a cleaner way to do it?

**UPD:**
I replaced the sendajax function content with some other code (without sending ajax) and found out that ajax is not the one causing the problem. It still enters the function twice.

Comment: Are there any iframes on the page?

Comment: No, this is a a part of a test page that has only some text and a link

Comment: Can you provide an example? Also, what browser are you seeing this happen in?

Comment: this is the only code after the head tag: '<body>
    sssssss
    <a href="http://www.www.ww">abc</a>
  </body>'  I've tried it in Chrome16 and Firefox3.6 both on Ubuntu

Comment: Odd, I can't get the event to fire multiple time on my Windows 7 machine in any browser. If you try this jsFiddle that mimics your code: http://jsfiddle.net/rWKdR/ does it happen twice?

Comment: I think i've got it! It looks like the A tag is causing the error, or rather the dodgy href. I've just altered my answer below to reflect what I just found, with an example.

Comment: Thank you so much @beeglebug!!!!! The problem was that the link was www.www  - when I changed it to www.google.com it worked perfetcly. Just write it as an answer so that I could vote for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the code in your edit and comments, it looks like it could simply be caused by the broken link you are clicking to leave the page.

Given the following code:

```
<script>
    function doSomething() { console.log('onbeforeunload fired'); }
    window.onbeforeunload = doSomething;
</script>
<a href="garbage">link A</a>
<a href="http://google.com">link B</a>
```

If I click on link A, I get two console log entries, if I click on link B I only get one.

It looks like it could be a quirk of how the browsers handle their internal "This web page has not been found" pages, causing your page to be refreshed and closed again before showing the message, leaving you with two occurrences of the onbeforeunload event.

Comment: I have found that the behavior of the beforeunload event varies significantly (especially regarding how many times it is called) depending on the IE document mode. the more recent and more standard behavior fires less frequently than the older backward-compatible (IE10) compatibility behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it took a while to understand and resolve, sharing the case details:

There was a custom JS within our template that manipulated the menu.
It caused the unload to fire twice, only when clicking on the menu links, not on other links, and only in IE/EDGE.

We eventually stopped the propagation on these links and the problem was resolved.

```
$('.SELECTOR a[href^="http://"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It's a specific bug in your application, therefore you won't find too much information on google.

Answer (score 1):

In React/Next js, I also encounter same issue. my `beforeunload` event fire 3-4 times. I just solve this issue by adding a `removeEventListener`.

Now its fire only 1 time.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("zzzzzzzzzzzzz 003 ",formLoadingState)

        const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
            console.log("zzzzzzzzzzzzz 033 ",formLoadingState)

            if (formLoadingState) {
                event.preventDefault()
                event.returnValue = ''
            }
        }
        
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload)
        }
    }, [formLoadingState])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><br>
     window.onbeforeunload=function sendajax(){<br>
        $.ajax({<br>
          url: "someurl",<br>
          data: mydata,<br>
          async : false<br>
        });<br>
};<br>
</script>
```

or you can define `sendajax() {}` at some place and the use it like `onbeforeunload = "sendajax()"` not as `onbeforeunload = "function () { sendajax() }"`

Comment: What is the purpose of naming an inline function? You can't refer to sendajax afterwards, it seems redundant.

Comment: @beeglebug:You are right, this is the case when you want to use the function only once.
If you want to use the function you can define it at some other place and should call like onbeforeload ="sendajax()"
not like onbeforeload ="function(){ sendajax() }"
because here the sendajax is being called two times first when defining the function (note not sendajax() the outer one) and after deinition the outer function itself gets called once which again calls the sendajax().

Comment: I have changes 'window.onbeforeunload=function(){sendajax();};' to 'window.onbeforeunload="sendajax()";' and to 'window.onbeforeunload="sendajax();";' and 'window.onbeforeunload="sendajax";'.   None of the above worked at all. The function just didn't execute.

Comment: You can also call the function as window.onbeforeunload = sendajax;
and you have to pass an event argument to the sendajax function when defining like function sendajax(e) {}

Answer (score 0):

**beforeUnload is cancellable**

I know this post is quite old but from the Chrome Pagelifecycle API documentation, browsers can occasionally partially unload pages to save resources. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api beforeUnload is not reliable to make sure that the page is closed. This especially happens on android devices when the screen is locked.

There is a jsfiddle that I found somebody wrote that you can test out https://jsfiddle.net/ov6b9pdL/. Keep the screen locked for 5-10 minutes on Chrome android and you'll see that beforeUnload is fired without even closing the tab.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', showLoader);
});

var showLoader = function() {
    $('#loader').show();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with AlonMichaeli's concept.
In my application there was anchor tag wrapped with in a div together with couple of spans. When Anchor was clicked on a dirty page, there was couple of 'Leave site' notifications.
It worked fine if any other part of menuItem (div or spans) are clicked.
So in custom javascript method I've added stopped propagation and preventDefault only if anchor tag is clicked. Somehow in this case preventDefault is necessary.

```
function menuItemClicked(event: JQueryEventObject) {
  var item = $(event.target);
  if (item.is(".anchor-item")) { 
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  href = item.closest(".anchor-item").attr("href");
  if (!event.ctrlKey && href) {
    window.location.href = href;
  }
}
```